# T-SQL Backup Database command for file path with spaces?

Tags: t-sql, file, backup

How do I write a T-SQL backup database command to specify a file containing spaces?
Here is what I have:

```
BACKUP DATABASE AMDMetrics TO DISK = 'C:\Documents and Settings\daultrd\My Documents\DatabaseBackups\AMD_METRICS.DAT'
```

And this is the error I get:

> Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot open backup device 'C:\Documents and Settings\daultrd\My Documents\DatabaseBackups\AMD_METRICS.DAT'. Operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: Have you created the `DatabaseBackups` folder under `My Documents` and verified that the path is correct?

Comment: Joe, can u look at my comments below and advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sharing your intended destination folder and using a UNC path to backup from the server to your local machine.

```
BACKUP DATABASE AMDMetrics 
    TO DISK = '\\YourMachineName\SharedFolderName\AMD_METRICS.DAT'
```

Comment: You won't believe this, but I can't share any of my local folders!  I can't believe this!  They have everything locked down.  So maybe there is no solution for me?!

Comment: The former is a system stored procedure used to invoke shell commands (typically, to run external programs). And the latter is a Windows native console ftp client program. You could (try to) use it to upload an *already saved* backup file to some accessible ftp server (then of course to download it to your machine).

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, are you sure that the directory is correct?

```
backup database master to disk = 'c:\Test Me\master.bak'


Processed 41728 pages for database 'master', file 'master' on file 1.
Processed 5 pages for database 'master', file 'mastlog' on file 1.
BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 41733 pages 
in 22.911 seconds (14.230 MB/sec).
```

copy and paste this into explorer and see if you can get there  `C:\Documents and Settings\daultrd\My Documents\DatabaseBackups`

This of course has to be the same machine, otherwise you need to map a drive to the location or use UNC paths

Comment: I typed it in there, and yes I can get there.

Comment: is the DB server your local machine? If not then it won't be able to see and you need a UNC path then

Comment: no, DB server is not my local machine.  Problem is that I don't have copy permissions on server machine.

Answer (score 1):

I was working through this issue as well.

It's possibly that the Service that SQL Server is running under (Network Service by Default) doesn't have permission to the folder specified.

```
BACKUP DATABASE master TO DISK = 'master1.bak' WITH INIT
```

The above should backup to the default backup folder
if that works with no problem it'll be the problem stated.